# Perl WWW::Mechanize and authenticated proxy

Tags: perl, mechanize

I have a proxy with IP, Port, Login and Password.
Is it possible to use this proxy with Perl's [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.66/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I'm not sure if there's a native way but here's a workaround which is claimed to work:

   http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=269358

   It's based on setting `$ENV{HTTP_PROXY}` to "http://login:password@proxyserver" where both login and password must be URI-encoded.
2. Also, WWW::Mechanize is a subclass of `LWP::UserAgent`, and as such, what works in LWP should work on Mechanize (example from [LWP Cookbook, PROXIES section](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl/lwpcook.pod#PROXIES))

   ```
   use LWP::UserAgent;
   $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;  
   $ua->proxy(['http', 'ftp'] => 'http://username:password@proxy.myorg.com');
   $req = HTTP::Request->new('GET',"http://www.perl.com");
   $res = $ua->request($req);  
   print $res->decoded_content if $res->is_success;
   ```